# RESTful HTTP Examples of Server <-> Client

Tags: xml, http, rest, post

So I'm looking up how to do POST, PUT, etc... in REST but I'm having a problem trying to find a simple example of using POST to send an XML example to a server say Tomcat and show the results.

Is there a correct way to connect? I've seen some people use sockets but is that the way I want to do?

Comment: What language are you writing the client in?

Comment: Send using what? Show the results where?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out cURL and libcurl.  They'll cover all your http needs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAVA, I am currently using Apache HTTPClient library to write client methods for invoking GET,POST,PUT & DELETE REST operations. It is straightforward to use and the JAR can be either downloaded from their site or can be searched in the Maven Global Repositories if you are using Maven. I've also heard about Jersey Client API for calling REST operations but have not implemented them.
URL for Apache HTTPClient : http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Answer (score 0):

REST is an architectural software design concept. There isn't really a "wrong" way to interact with an existing rest based service as long as you are following the rules that the provider of the RESTfull service have hopefully provided.  That being said different protocol, transport, login, format, etc standards used have specific requirements.  So you would work with a tool that can provide HTML requests required by the REST implementation you are dealing with.  However the data and how it is represented in a payload might be different from service to service.  One service may use POST with HTML headers for authentication and post data stored in an XML string that matches an element definition from a provided schema.  Another service may have strayed from a rest best practice and uses a get request to a specific URL to "post" data and then you will have to know the query string format and use your http library or tool to munge it up for you based on it's Apis.  The nature of REST and that in practice many RESTfull type of services will not work in the exact same way will make it hard to find consistent of examples.

If your use case is to post data at a URL resource using XML over http just get any library out there for your development system that supports http requests and tell it to make a POST request to that URL with your XML data.  The format of that data, if you need to add headers, and if there is a response and how that response conveys meaning will need to be figured out from the rest service vendor's documentation or looking at everything in the response yourself and figuring it out.

If you need specifics about XML, schema, http, hmac-sha1 or anything like that the specs and tools to do it is abundant and easily found.  If your wanting specifics about the rest service payloads for requests and responses and the supported operations on certain uri resources your best bet is to ask the vendor providing it or finding their docs.

Sorry for any typos or grammar issues, I'm on a mobile device and I'll update this later to try to fix those kind of issues.